# PHP getter method question

Tags: php, methods, getter

Hi Im new to PHP so forgive the basic nature of this question.

I have a class: "CustomerInfo.php" which Im including in another class. Then I am trying to set a variable of CustomerInfo object with the defined setter method and Im trying to echo that variable using the getter method. Problem is the getter is not working. But if I directly access the variable I can echo the value. Im confused....

```
    <?php
class CustomerInfo
{

    public $cust_AptNum;



    public function _construct()
    {
        echo"Creating new CustomerInfo instance<br/>";
        $this->cust_AptNum = "";

    }

    public function setAptNum($apt_num)
    {
        $this->cust_AptNum = $apt_num;
    }

    public function getAptNum()
    {
        return $this->cust_AptNum;
    }


}
?>
```

---

```
<?php

include ('CustomerInfo.php');
$CustomerInfoObj = new CustomerInfo();

$CustomerInfoObj->setAptNum("22");
//The line below doesn't output anything
echo "CustomerAptNo = $CustomerInfoObj->getAptNum()<br/>";
//This line outputs the value that was set
echo "CustomerAptNo = $CustomerInfoObj->cust_AptNum<br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
echo 'CustomerAptNo = ' . $CustomerInfoObj->getAptNum() . '<br/>';
```

Or you will need to place the method call with in a "Complex (curly) syntax"

```
echo "CustomerAptNo = {$CustomerInfoObj->getAptNum()} <br/>";
```

As your calling a method, not a variable with in double quotes.

Comment: A thing to consider is to always use single quotes for your strings. Makes PHP go faster and there are never problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

for concat string and variables, you can use sprintf method for better perfomace of you app

instead of this:

```
echo "CustomerAptNo = $CustomerInfoObj->getAptNum()<br/>";
```

do this:

```
echo sprintf("CustomerAptNo = %s <br />", $CustomerInfoObj->getAptNum());
```

check http://php.net/sprintf for more details